# XML serialization error in SQL Server when concatenating characters

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to concatenate a number of characters corresponding to some ints (the first 15 ASCII characters for example):

```
;with cte as (
select 1 nr
union all
select nr + 1
from cte
where nr <= 15)
select (
    select char(nr)
    from cte
    for xml path (''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

but I'm getting an error saying:

> Msg 6841, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> FOR XML could not serialize the
> data for node 'NoName' because it contains a character (0x0001) which
> is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it
> to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64
> directive.

Even if I try to modify my CTE's seed from 1 to 10 for example, I still get the error but for a different character, `0x000B`.

I have two possible solutions I'm looking for:

- find a way to concatenate all the characters (any other method than using `FOR XML`) - **preferred solution**

or

- remove all characters that are not allowed in XML - I've tried this but it seems I just hit other non-allowed characters. I've also looked for a list of these non-allowed characters but I couldn't find one.

Any help is very much appreciated.

**Update - context:**

This is part of a bigger CTE where I'm trying to generate random character sets from random numbers by doing multiple divisions and modulus operations.

I modulo each number by 256, get the result, turn it into its corresponding `CHAR()` and then dividing the number by 256 and so on until it's modulo or division is 0.

In the end I want to concatenate all of these characters. I have everything in place, I'm just encountering this error which does not allow me to concatenate the generated strings from `CHAR()`.

This might sound weird and you might say that it's not a SQL-task and you can do it in other languages, but I want to try and find a solution in SQL, no matter how low the performance is.

Comment: What does your data look like? `0x001` isn't a printable character.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to generate data. Turning 1 into a character, through `CHAR(1)` then `CHAR(2)` etc. and at the end concatenate them. I'll expand this to work for any number (taking into consideration that there are 256 ASCII characters, so I'll use `%` moving forward, but I have that part covered).

Comment: You can't use the XML PATH method then, not without XML encoding the data first. Aaron Bertrand covers all available methods to aggregate strings [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation). The fastest and safest is to use a SQLCLR custom aggregate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was just looking at the post from your comment on the answer below. Thanks.

Comment: Is using characters necessary? Can you consider instead using the hex values of each character and storing them as `binary`/`varbinary`?

Comment: Just *don't* use such characters. Avoid non-printable characters and use `UNICODE()` instead of `CHAR()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hmm, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Start from 32 (Space). That's the first printable character

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Starting from 32 did the trick! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XML PATH` is just one of the techniques used for grouped concatenation. Aaron Bertrand explains and compares all of them in [Grouped Concatenation in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation). Built-in support for this is coming in the next version of SQL Server in the form of `STRING_AGG`.

Bertrand's article explains that `XML PATH` can only work with XML safe characters. Non-printable characters like `0x1` (SOH) and `0xB` (Vertical Tab) won't work without XML encoding the data first. Typically, this isn't a problem because real data *doesn't* contain non-printable charactes - what would a SOH and VT look like on a text box?

Perhaps, the easiest way to solve your problem is to use `UNICODE()` instead of `CHAR()` to generate Unicode characters and start form 32 instead of 0 or 1.

For now, the fastest and safest method to aggregate strings is to use a SQLCLR custom aggregate. If you don't use sloppy techniques like concatenating strings directly, it will also consume the least amount of memory.The various `GROUP_CONCAT` implementations shown [in this project](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/) are small enough that you can copy and use in your own projects. They will work with any Unicode character too, even with non-printable ones.

BTW, SQL Server vNext brings `STRING_AGG` to aggregate strings. We'll just have to wait a year or two.

The non-ordered version, `GROUP_CONCAT` is just 99 lines. It simply collects all strings in a dictionary and writes them out at the end:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace GroupConcat
{
    [Serializable]
    [SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined,
                             MaxByteSize = -1,
                             IsInvariantToNulls = true,
                             IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,
                             IsInvariantToOrder = true,
                             IsNullIfEmpty = true)]
    public struct GROUP_CONCAT : IBinarySerialize
    {
        private Dictionary<string, int> values;

        public void Init()
        {
            this.values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }

        public void Accumulate([SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)] SqlString VALUE)
        {
            if (!VALUE.IsNull)
            {
                string key = VALUE.Value;
                if (this.values.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    this.values[key] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.values.Add(key, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Merge(GROUP_CONCAT Group)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in Group.values)
            {
                string key = item.Key;
                if (this.values.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    this.values[key] += Group.values[key];
                }
                else
                {
                    this.values.Add(key, Group.values[key]);
                }
            }
        }

        [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
        public SqlString Terminate()
        {
            if (this.values != null && this.values.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder returnStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in this.values)
                {
                    for (int value = 0; value < item.Value; value++)
                    {
                        returnStringBuilder.Append(item.Key);
                        returnStringBuilder.Append(",");
                    }
                }
                return returnStringBuilder.Remove(returnStringBuilder.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void Read(BinaryReader r)
        {
            int itemCount = r.ReadInt32();
            this.values = new Dictionary<string, int>(itemCount);
            for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++)
            {
                this.values.Add(r.ReadString(), r.ReadInt32());
            }
        }

        public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
        {
            w.Write(this.values.Count);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> s in this.values)
            {
                w.Write(s.Key);
                w.Write(s.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the OP uses a recursive/iterative CTE there's no need for this. The string concatenation can be done *step by step* within the CTE...

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach (works with *non-printables* too):

You are adding one character after each other. You do not need any group concatenation at all. Your recursive (rather iterativ) CTE is a *hidden RBAR* on its own and will do this for you.

The following example uses a list of ints (considering your use case where you need to do this with random numbers) as input:

```
DECLARE @SomeInts TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,intVal INT);
INSERT INTO @SomeInts VALUES(36),(33),(39),(32),(35),(37),(1),(2),(65);

WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT ID,intVal AS nr,CAST(CHAR(intVal) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS targetString FROM @SomeInts WHERE ID=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT si.ID,intVal + 1,targetString + CHAR(intVal)
    FROM @SomeInts AS si
    INNER JOIN cte ON si.ID=cte.ID+1
)
SELECT targetString, CAST(targetString AS varbinary(max)) 
FROM cte

option (maxrecursion 0);
```

The result (*printed* and as *growing hex list* --> beware of `x01` and `x02`):

[image]